# How do i make View Controllers's Animation as like in Inshorts App but in horizontal direction

Tags: ios, swift

**I'm working on an ios(Swift) project**. In this project i want to read stories by fetching from a particular api.

1. But the problem is that i want only one story on my View and when i swipe right the another view with another story come from left with the effect that it is overlapping the story which is on the present view and so on until the story persist on the api.
2. And again when i swipe left, the most recent view(which was most recently get overlapped) with their respective story will come from right and give the effect like, it is overlapping the view which is present view at now.
3. And vice versa mentioned in above two points.

How can i achieve this in ios i don't. If anyone knows how to do it, please help me. I'm waiting for answers

NOTE: I don't want the pushing effect like in horizontal ScrollView. I only want the overlapping effect.

Answer (score 4):

You should use 'UIPageViewController' and adjust 'transitionStyle' what you want.